# Sinusoidal functions

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I need to plot a graph of the following function for values time, $0≤t≤2π$ to $2π$ (radians).
$$y=5\sin\left(2t+\frac{π}{6}\right)$$
I need to describe and define the amplitude, periodic time and frequency. Can the formula be put into Excel somehow to plot the graph?

Thanks

Comment: Excel prefers to plot "data", as opposed to "formulas". For an alternative, try fooplot.com and enter the formula "5*sin (2x+pi/6)"

Answer (score 1):

Your function has an amplitude $A=5$, a period $T=\pi$ and a phase shift $\psi=\pi/6$.

You can use  a spread sheet to visualize the graph. A simple way is illustrated in the figures.

[image]

You can see the formula used in the column $C$, and in  $B3$ the formula is simply $=B2+\$A\$2$. Changing the step in $A2$ you can have les or more points in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

For a sinusoid of the form $y = A\sin\left(Bx \pm C \right) \pm D$, $A$ represents the **amplitude**, $C$ gives the **phase shift** (how far it is shifted over to the left or to the right), and we get the **period time** by the relation $T = 2\pi/B$.

Since $A=5$, the amplitude is $\boxed{5}$. The period time is $T = 2\pi/2 = \boxed{\pi}$. Since it completes one period by $t = \pi$, then it completes two periods by $t = 2\pi$, so its frequency is $\boxed{2}$.